# Geocoding a Custom Field in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps, geocoding

I have hundreds of posts with an address custom field, sometimes the field is an excerpt. I pull the address from these fields depending on the custom post type it is, so that is sorted out. I then was hoping to create a function in functions.php that I could pass this address to and generate the map.

I have looked around and I have tried the following code but it only works in Chrome, what am I doing wrong? It does not work in FF and IE.

```
function make_map($address) {

    $google_api_key = 'API';

    if($address): ?>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=3&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=<?php echo $google_api_key; ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 250px; height: 250px"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function showAddress(address) 
    {
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
        var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
        geocoder.getLatLng(
            address,
            function(point) 
            {
                if (!point) 
                {
                alert(address + " not found");
                } 
                else 
                {
                map.setCenter(point, 13);
                var marker = new GMarker(point);
                map.addOverlay(marker);
                }
            }
        );
    }
    showAddress("<?php echo $address; ?>");
    </script>
    <br>
    <?php endif;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That shouldn't work in any browser.  You are using the Google Maps API v2 syntax, but including the Google Maps API v3.

Note that the Google Maps API v2 is deprecated and may stop working May 2013.